# Attach terminal to different Java process

Tags: java

I have my terminal open running my Java application.
At some point, my code starts a ProcessBuilder instance & builds a process, which runs in the background, but it stores a reference to the Process which the main program can access.

Is it possible for my program to swap to these different process 'screens' in the same terminal?

Thank you. I want this to work similarly to the linux screen package.

Comment: Maybe actually use screen or tmux in the command to `ProcessBuilder`?

Comment: I want to try and get this to work on both Windows & Linux though, so I can't do that although that would be a good solution otherwise!

Comment: I can't think then other than to collect the result of the process and visualise that in the terminal when you want to.